# Why is HttpRequestMessage decoding my encoded string

Tags: c#, httprequest

I am trying to make a `Http` request, like the following:

```
var category = Uri.EscapeDataString("Power Tools");

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"/api/Items/GetAll?category={category}");
```

`category` now equals: `Power%20Tools`

The request gets translated to:

```
request = {Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://localhost/api/Items/GetAll?category=Power Tools', ...
```

Why is `HttpRequestMessage` decoding my encoded string?

Comment: Where do you read the request?

Comment: @vernou I am debugging the method. I just hover over it. I have a Regular Expression validating input at the controller. It doesn't accept spaces.

Comment: I think you're going to need to include more detail. I just did a quick test and I don't see the same behavior.

Comment: @vernou I see `http://localhost/api/Items/GetAll?category=Power%20Tools`. However, the controller is seeing `Power Tools` and responds with an error message. My regex is `^[a-zA-Z0-9%]+$`. This works if I add a space to the regex.

Comment: The controller would also see `Power Tools` if you just went to the address in your browser. This is something that ASP.NET handles for you. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: To be clearer: the value of Category is "Power Tools", but to represent it clearly in the URL we have to escape it (thus it becomes "Power%20Tools"). Because escaping just makes the URL work, it is decoded when ASP.NET passes it to the controller method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduce in Console app in .NET 5. I think, it's just the `ToString` that decode the url to be friendly on debug information. I don't find a information to this on the documentation, but .NET is now open source.

Generaly, the method `ToString` is used to generate debug information. See
See the source code of [HttpRequestMessage.ToString](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpRequestMessage.cs#L155) :

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("Method: ");
    sb.Append(method);

    sb.Append(", RequestUri: '");
    sb.Append(requestUri == null ? "<null>" : requestUri.ToString());
    ...
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This just display `requsetUri.ToString()` and `requestUri` is type of `Uri`.
From the official documentation of [Uri.String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.tostring?view=net-5.0):

> The unescaped canonical representation of the Uri instance. All characters are unescaped except #, ?, and %.

```cs
// Create a new Uri from a string address.
Uri uriAddress = new Uri("HTTP://www.Contoso.com:80/thick%20and%20thin.htm");

// Write the new Uri to the console and note the difference in the two values.
// ToString() gives the canonical version.  OriginalString gives the orginal
// string that was passed to the constructor.

// The following outputs "http://www.contoso.com/thick and thin.htm".
Console.WriteLine(uriAddress.ToString());

// The following outputs "HTTP://www.Contoso.com:80/thick%20and%20thin.htm".
Console.WriteLine(uriAddress.OriginalString);
```